# Dependencies Injection configuration for XtextDocumentProvider

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, xtext

I want to extend the class XtextDocumentProvider, which is created by dependencies injection of google injections.
I want to extend this class in order to extend a method for internal needs but I don't know where is XtextDocumentProvider being configured so that the extended class will be inject instead of it.
How can i found the injection point or configuration or is it a xtext xml that i'm missing?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All bindings are established in the Runtime and UI module of your language. That means, that all methods that follow the naming pattern `bindABC` or `provideABC` are invoked reflectively implying that you are free to add arbitrary additional bindings. In addition to these explicit bindings, there is the concept of just-in-time bindings, e.g. if an injection point requires an XtextDocumentProvider, but there is no explicit binding for that class, and the class is not abstract, it'll be used directly. If you want to customize that, you are free to use something like

```
public Class<? extends XtextDocumentProvider> bindXtextDocumentProvider() {
    return MyDocumentProvider.class;
}
```

Comment: Although `XtextDocumentProvider` is not one of them but to be complete: There are a few classes which are configured using the `@ImplementedBy` mechanism of Guice. They are a little bit harder to track down.